# Bash error suppresion

Tags: bash, php

I'm using PHP script from cli, the script calls exec() few times. There are some minor errors sometimes, which are handled by php script. I'm suppressing the errors by appending 2>/dev/null to the end of each command... Is there any way to achieve that without adding the forementioned?

Answer (score 1):

If you use [proc_open](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) instead of exec, you should get more control over the file descriptors.